# Send Ajax with an model internal error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an mvc3 project.

I am trying to send an ajax post request from my JS code, problem is I am getting an internal error and when I am debugging it the method is not even invoked.

This is my Js code:

```
ajaxCallTest: function (url, dataObj) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: dataObj,
        success: function (result) {
        }
        ,
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
}
```

This is my C# code:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Transaction(PaymentModel model) 
{
...
}
```

Now when I try:

```
ajaxCallTest('..url/Transaction', ''); <- enters 'Transaction' with null values...
```

But when I do:

```
ajaxCallTest('..url/Transaction', model); <--- the model is in type of PaymentModel
```

The second code does not enter the `'Transaction'` method, `instead I get 500 - internal error`.

Why is that?

**Edited:**

```
var dataObj = { Id: 11, Description: "hh" };

$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
        success: function (result) {
            //window.location.replace(result);
            var form = $(result);
            $(form).submit();
        }
        ,
        error: function (result) {
            console.log('Error ' + result);
            //cardStrip.fail();
        }
    });
```

Comment: just use JSON.stringify(dataObj) in $.ajax() when u r posting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataObj model needs to match your `PaymentModel` e.g:

If `PaymentModel` looks like this:

```
public class PaymentModel
{
    var int Id{get; set;}
    var string Description{get; set;}
}
```

Then your javascript should look something like this:

```
// create an object that represents PaymentModel
var dataObj = {Id: $('myId').val(), Description: $('#MyDescription').val()};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data:  JSON.stringify(dataObj)
```

Comment: thanks, Now it enters the function but my model is full 'nulls'. my dataobj looks exactly like my model. very weird :/

Comment: Further i copied your exact coed and same result.

Comment: Show the code that you are using to populate the dataObj model

Comment: I used your example for instance, take a look at my edit

Comment: You've used my PaymentModel example, it needs to look like YOUR PaymentModel. Can you add the code for your PaymentModel.

Comment: ah ok, just checking... That is weird, I don't really know what to suggest.  Maybe add `dataType: 'json',` and
`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`